# Int.ToString format equivalent to String.Format("{0,9}" , int)

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Is there any value of `formatString` such that:

```
intValue.ToString(formatString) == String.Format("{0,9}", intValue)
```

for all positive integer values up to 1 million?

In particular, the output must be 9 characters and padded with spaces at the start.

`000000000` will give me the correct length but padded with zeros.

As to why I don't just use `String.Format("{0,9}", intValue)`, I am trying to create a configuration file which a third party program will read and use to create an output file and I cannot change the code in this program. I know the program is written in C# and it is obvious from the current configuration file that it uses `ToString()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

[Composite format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/txafckwd.aspx) (`{0:xxx}`) are not supported by any of the `ToString` overloads, though the [standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) are supported by the methods that do use composite format strings.

> Standard numeric format strings are also supported by the .NET Framework composite formatting feature, which is used by some Write and WriteLine methods of the Console and StreamWriter classes, the String.Format method, and the StringBuilder.AppendFormat method.